# What kind of date format is this and how do I transform it?

Tags: ruby, json, date, datetime

Making a GET request to a **private** (no public documentation) API returns data in JSON format.

The value for date looks as follows:

`AanmeldDatum: "/Date(1262300400000+0100)/"`

There's another variable called `AangebodenSindsTekst` which means `OfferedSinceText` and it's value is `"8 augustus 2014"`. So the unknown Date format should get parsed into that specific value.

I'm wondering what kind of date format it is and how can I transform this to something like this `2014-08-08` with Ruby?

I've tried this:

```
require 'time'

t = '1262300400000+0100'

t2 = Time.parse(t)  

# => ArgumentError: no time information in "1262300400000+0100"
```

Comment: Doesn't the API offer any documentation about its date format? Can you give us any information about what kind of system this is?

Comment: No it doesn't, it's a private API. Unfortunately I don't know anything about the system.

Comment: As to the question of format, it was [invented at Microsoft](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dates-and-json), and found in code that uses `JavaScriptSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  The newer ASP.Net WebAPI frameworks use Json.net instead, and encourage the use of ISO8601 formatting.  It is sometimes referred to as an "ASP.NET JSON Date", and is supported in some "modern" libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Tin Man pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263488/why-is-time-strptime-returning-the-current-date) answer, use the following instead:

`Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%Q%z')`

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's Time class is your friend, especially the [`strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-strptime) method:

```
require 'time'

foo = Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%N') # => 2014-08-08 16:57:25 -0700
foo = Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%N%z') # => 2014-08-08 08:57:25 -0700
```

`%N` tells Ruby to use nanoseconds. It's throwing away the precision after the 9th digit which is OK if you don't need the rest of the value. Nanosecond accuracy is good enough for most of us.

`%z` tells Ruby to find the timezone offset, which it then applies to the returned value.

While `parse` can often figure out how to tear apart an incoming string, it's not bullet-proof, nor is it all-knowing. For speed, I'd recommend learning and relying on `strptime` if your strings are consistent.

Comment: Doing `foo = Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%N')` returns the current time and date `# =>  2014-08-09 09:18:35 +0200`. Same goes for `foo = Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%N%z')` it returns `# => 2014-08-09 10:19:29 +0200`. I'm using Ruby 2.1.2. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score -1):

it could be milliseconds since epoc, take off the last 3 zeros and plug it into a unix time stamp converter, comes out as Dec 31st 2009

TIME STAMP: 1262300400

DATE (M/D/Y @ h:m:s): 12 / 31 / 09 @ 11:00:00pm UTC

Comment: And the +0100 just signifies the time zone which is a standard format

Comment: I noticed a value called `AangebodenSindsTekst` which means `OfferedSinceText` and it's value is `"8 augustus 2014"`. So the Date format should get parsed into that specific value.