# Why is Time.strptime() returning the current date?

Tags: asp.net, ruby, json, time, strptime

Making a GET request to a private (no public documentation) API returns data in JSON format.

The value im interested in is the date. It returns the date in ASP.NET JSON Date format. Here's what it looks like:

```
AanmeldDatum: "/Date(1406675114000+0200)/"
```

There's another variable called AangebodenSindsTekst which means OfferedSinceText and it's value is "8 augustus 2014". So the unknown Date format should get parsed into that specific value.

I've tried this:

```
require 'time'

foo = Time.strptime('1406675114000+0200', '%N') # => 2014-08-12 13:38:46 +0200
foo = Time.strptime('1406675114000+0200', '%N%z') # => 2014-08-12 14:38:58 +0200
```

But it simply returns the current time.

I know 100% sure that `/Date(1406675114000+0200)/` when parsed, should return the date `2014-07-30`.

The question is how do I make sure it does?

Comment: Any idea about the RFC type of this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not Arup.

Comment: the number you have, if calculated as time from epoch is 2010-01-01. If you want to get it from `Time.strptime` you should use `%Q%z`, not `%N%z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `'%N'` or `'%N%z'` seems to trigger a bug in `strptime`, resulting in the current date/time:

```
Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%N') # => 2014-08-14 16:30:01 -0700
Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%N%z') # => 2014-08-14 08:30:01 -0700
```

Using `'%Q%z'` parses to:

```
Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%Q%z') # => 2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0100
```

The [`Time.strptime` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-strptime) doesn't mention `'%Q'`, but the [`DateTime.strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-strptime) doc does.

If you have parsed the date string, then formatting it is easy:

```
foo = Time.strptime('1262300400000+0100', '%Q%z') # => 2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0100
foo.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') # => "2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0100"
```

See [the `strftime` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for more information about your formatting options.

Notice that there are some shortcuts for things like `'%Y-%m-%d'` and `'%H:%M:%S'`:

```
foo.strftime('%F %T %z') # => "2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0100"
```

The real problem is how .NET is serializing the date in JSON. A search of the googles shows a number of pages talking about this:

- "[Dealing with JSON Dates in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html)"
- "[On the nightmare that is JSON Dates. Plus, JSON.NET and ASP.NET Web API](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)"

.NET isn't alone in doing this. Ruby's JSON and YAML serializers will occasionally do similar things, and the fix is to look at the JSON being output, and then provide `to_json` or `to_s` or `to_h` handlers that will result in JSON output that best represents the data. JSON is supposed to be transferable between JavaScript and backend systems, and .NET isn't the only language offering that capability. Perl, Ruby, Python, and who knows how many other languages can parse and emit JSON, and they all need to play by the same rules.

Comment: I want it to return `2014-08-08 **:**:** +0200`. How could I make sure it does?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean. Do you want it to mask the time value with `'*'`? Do you want it to reflect a different timezone than the LOCALE based one?

Comment: I know 100% sure that `1262300400000+0100` should return the date `2014-08-08`. But since I don't know the time or timezone for that specific value, I'm leaving those blank. Hence the `*`.

Comment: Apologies. It should have been the value `1406675114000+0200` and it should return the date `2014-07-30`. Using `Time.strptime('1406675114000+0200', '%Q%z')` it does. Thank you.

Comment: Nice job @theTinMan. Here's some more on JSON dates in .NET: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx